# Why is it "five-barred gate" not "five-bar gate"?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, modifiers

Is the "bar" here a past participle? Why it needs to be added an "-ed"?

Another example I recently encountered is "pink-haired girl". "Hair" is a noun, why add "-ed"?

And we always say "5-year-old boy" not "5-year-olded boy", right?

Comment: May be not "5-year-olded boy" but definitely "teenaged boy" .

Comment: @Kris isn't that just because *to age* is a verb? Like a *matured wine*. *To old*, on the other hand, is not a verb.

Answer (score -1):

It's a form of modifier derived from the past **participle** of a verb, indeed.

A "pink hair" girl could be a girl with pink hair, a girl who sells pink hair, a girl who is also known as "pink hair", so on. OTOH, a "pink haired" girl is one who has been "endowed with pink hair," so to speak -- she has been given pink hair or "pink haired".

Comment: Do you have any citations that can confirm that this usage comes from the past participle of a verb?

Comment: @sumelic What is Google for!

Comment: The [dictionary.com entry for "barred"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/barred) says "**Origin of barred**:
Middle English word dating back to 1300–50; see origin at bar¹, -ed³". The [entry for -ed³](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/-ed) says "a suffix forming adjectives from nouns". It is separate from the entry for -ed²
"a suffix forming the past participle of weak verbs".

Comment: @sumelic Google harder! Good Luck.

Comment: No source I have found says that words like "five-barred" are necessarily derived from verbs. The OED entry for the relevant suffix "-ed" defines it as a suffix that "is appended to nouns in order to form adjectives connoting the possession or the presence of the attribute or thing expressed by the noun" and says "it is possible that the Germanic -ôđjo- may originally have been < -ôđo- (see -ed suffix¹), the suffix of past participles of verbs in -ôjan formed upon nouns [...] In modern English, and even in Middle English, the form affords no means of distinguishing between the genuine...

Comment: examples of this suffix and those participial adjectives in -ed suffix¹  which are ultimately < nouns through unrecorded verbs", but this is an etymological detail. It seems to me that it would be meaningless to say "the form affords no means of distinguishing between the genuine examples of this suffix and those participial adjectives in -ed suffix¹ which are ultimately < nouns through unrecorded verbs" if there was a consensus that all words with this suffix are derived from some verb. Please give a specific source that supports this answer rather than just telling me to "Google harder".